# Biblatex: Attach "'s" to author name in citations

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib, biber

I am using `biblatex` with `biber` as backend and `natbib` loaded. What I am trying to achieve is appending an author's name with `'s`, e.g. in a situation like:

> [...] as outlined in Krugman's (1989) early work

I could use `\citeauthor{krugman89}'s (\citeyear{krugman89})`, I suppose, but I was wondering whether there is a more direct way of appending the `'s` directly to the author's name. `\citet[]['s]{krugman89}` would not work, since this adds the `'s` after year in parenthesis, i.e. `Krugman (1989, 's)`.

Comment: You could define a new cite command. But first you should decide what you want to do if there is more then one author.

Comment: According to the question I indicated above, there are a simple solution which defines a new command (like @UlrikeFischer said) such as `\newcommand\posscite[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}` and a more complex and deep one which really fixes the problem.